# How to allow docker containers to see each other by their name?

Tags: docker

I have a mongo instance running in a container named `mongo1` that has exposed port 27017. 
I can connect just fine from the host.

I have another container that is running an application that wants to connect to the mongo instance.

How can I connect the 2 containers so that the hostname `mongo1` is exposed to the other container and it can connect to `mongo1:27017` ?

Comment: try linking between container concept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What was happening was that the default docker network doesn't allow `name >> DNS` mapping.

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

So I created a new network:

```
docker network create -d bridge br0
```

and then added the containers to that network:

```
docker network connect br0 mongo1
docker network connect br0 wiki
```

now they can see each other by their name.

Comment: Good find! Note however that `br0` is a misleading name, I would recommend something less "Linux:y" to avoid confusion. `example` would be a good example :)

Answer (score 1):

For existing containers (as Temporary solution)

```
docker inspect <mango_container_name> | grep IPAddress
```

and edite/add `/etc/hosts` inside the container

```
docker exec -it -u 0 <app_container_name> bash
```

then from inside the container map container_name with the IP address .. Example

```
echo "172.15.0.5 mango1" >> /etc/hosts

exit
```

.......
Or you can assign hostname for container during spining it up with

```
docker run -it -h mango1 mango_image
```

and/or add Example `echo "172.17.0.5 mango1" >> /etc/hosts` command in docker files for less headache